# How to change the Default Column value in sql server

Tags: sql, default

In my table while altering I gave '1' to the default. Now I need to reset the value for the default one, '0'. I tried the following script but it is throwing an error.

```
ALTER TABLE Order ADD Cancel BIT CONSTRAINT [DF_Order_Cancel] DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL;
```

Here I need to reset the default value to '0' instead of '1'.

I tried the script below but it's still throwing an error.

```
ALTER TABLE Order ADD DEFAULT (0) FOR Cancel
```

Comment: You should provide the given error.

Comment: Incorrect syntax for definition of the 'TABLE' constraint.

Answer (score 9):

First, delete the constraint.

```
alter table Order drop constraint DF_Order_Cancel
```

Then recreate it.

`ALTER TABLE Order ADD DEFAULT 0 FOR Cancel`

Edit: the following statements run fine.

```
ALTER TABLE Order ADD Cancel BIT CONSTRAINT [DF_Order_Cancel] DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL;
alter table Order drop constraint DF_Order_Cancel
ALTER TABLE Order ADD DEFAULT 0 FOR Cancel
```

Comment: i drop the constraint and i tried change the default value but it's not happening...

Comment: I have got some more error also...Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it.

Comment: Some Times i use to get like this how do i change this..                                                ALTER TABLE Order ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Cancel]    instead of '1' if i need to get '0' what was the solution

Comment: Have you tried my 3 lines of code? Or at least the #2 and #3?

Comment: I tried that's fine and thanks for your answer..But few of my conditions without constraint it was there... Which i have posted on top so in that case how could i can resolve that issue.

Comment: First time run the script and you write drop constraint then it's give error because no constraint available. So, you need to check first if constraint exists then drop the constraint. like. alter table [PhotoGallery] drop constraint IF EXISTS DF_PhotoGallery_IsDeleted

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the constraint name. Execute the code bellow and in the results you can see the constraint name.

```
sp_helpconstraint tableName
```

After you got the constraint name then you can use this code to change the default value for your column :

```
alter table tableName
drop constraint constraintName
go
alter table tableName
add constraint df_tableName_columnName default 0 for columnName
go
```